# Empty year in *.bib file

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I obtained this error:

```
empty year in Rivinius1998 Warning--empty year in Rivinius1998
```

Why is the year wrong?

*.bib

```
@ARTICLE{Rivinius1998,
       author = {{Rivinius}, T. and {Baade}, D. and {Stefl}, S. and {Stahl}, O. and {Wolf}, B. and {Kaufer}, A.},
        title = "{Stellar and circumstellar activity of the Be star MU Centauri. II. Multiperiodic low-order line-profile variability}",
      journal = {Astronomy Astrophysics},
     keywords = {STARS: EMISSION-LINE, BE, STARS: OSCILLATIONS, STARS: INDIVIDUAL: MU CEN\}},
         year = {1998},
        month = aug,
       volume = {336},
        pages = {177-190},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998A&A...336..177R},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

*.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}       
\begin{document}
\citep{Rivinius1998}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}   
\renewcommand{\bibname}{test.bib}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thank you. I have edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's due to the mismatched braces of `keywords`. Please try the following bib file:

```
@ARTICLE{Rivinius1998,
  author =   {{Rivinius}, T. and {Baade}, D. and {Stefl}, S. and
                  {Stahl}, O. and {Wolf}, B. and {Kaufer}, A.},
  title =    "{Stellar and circumstellar activity of the Be star
                  MU Centauri. II. Multiperiodic low-order
                  line-profile variability}",
  journal =  {Astronomy Astrophysics},
  keywords =     {STARS: EMISSION-LINE, BE, STARS: OSCILLATIONS,
                  STARS: INDIVIDUAL: MU CEN},
  year =     1998,
  month =    aug,
  volume =   336,
  pages =    {177-190},
  adsurl =
                  {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998A&A...336..177R},
  adsnote =  {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @ElenaGreg, you are very welcome.